# How to set base url to /subfolder in Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have uploaded my laravel 4.2 application to a `/subfolder` of a shared hosting like **www.example.com/bangla** by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16683938/3975838) answer.

Structure of my application is

```
example.com/    (the root of your web hosting)
|-- laravel4_base/   (Here goes all contents except public folder)
|-- [some other folders...]
|-- public_html/    
|   |-- [some other folders...]
|   |-- bangla/      (Here goes contents of public folder)
```

Now i have these menu link in my view

```
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/rj">Rj</a></li>
```

My problem is whenever i click them should route me to

```
www.example.com/bangla
www.example.com/bangla/rj
```

But it takes to

```
www.example.com
www.example.com/rj
```

My **route.php** looks like

```
Route::get('/','HomeController@index');
Route::get('rj','HomeController@rj');
```

**HomeController.php** looks like

```
public function index()
{
    return View::make('home');
}
public function rj()
{
    return View::make('rj');
}
```

So basically the base path is not being changed to subfolder **www.example.com/bangla**

I did a lot of searching in stackoverflow. Some are

[laravel 4 setting base url to /subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684866/laravel-4-setting-base-url-to-subfolder)

[How to set sub-directory for base URL of laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103555/how-to-set-sub-directory-for-base-url-of-laravel)

Also in [laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-4-setting-base-url-to-subfolder). But all are either unanswered or they do not have any answer that resolves the problem.

So, in simple words the question is how to change base url from **www.example.com** to **www.example.com/bangla**

Comment: Did you set the url in your app.php file? Can you set up a virtual host to that directory/sub-directory?

Comment: this url thing in app.php works for artisan related commands nothing to do with base i think @Revent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a URL that starts with `/` it will tell the browser that it is an absolute URL so the browser will natually start looking for it from root of your current URL, which is always the domain.

To prevent this, you can use laravel's helper functions to generate the URL for you.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls

```
<li><a href="{{ action('HomeController@index') }}">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ action('HomeController@rj') }}">Rj</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem too and m'm code like this

```
<a class='btn btn-warning' href='{{ url('/jobCatEdit/'.$dtJobCat->jcid) }}'>
```

and it's work